# Why does an error occur when calculating a route with sorting (here maps)

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps, heremap-navigation

My request:

```
https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?apikey=key&app_id=id&app_code=code&representation=display&routeAttributes=summary&alternatives=0&mapMatchTolerance=50&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&departure=2022-03-30T21:00:00Z&arrival=2022-04-01T21:00:00Z&waypoint0=48.44465178998905,34.96006029852592;opening:2022-03-30T21:00:00Z;before:1&waypoint1=48.47320445868704,34.991180295542904;opening:2022-03-30T21:05:00Z;closing:2022-03-30T21:45:00Z;sort&waypoint2=48.46401993067931,34.97867142166844;opening:2022-03-30T21:00:00Z;closing:2022-03-30T21:30:00Z;before:3;sort&waypoint3=48.47320458546018,35.00203403643033;opening:2022-03-30T21:45:00Z;closing:2022-03-30T22:30:00Z;sort&waypoint4=48.441562775905375,34.95594137232717;opening:2022-03-30T21:00:00Z;closing:2022-03-31T23:00:00Z;before:5;sort&waypoint5=48.41997419510783,35.06206354332796;opening:2022-03-30T23:00:00Z;closing:2022-04-01T21:00:00Z;sort
```

In response I have this error:

```
Cannot calculate route: Couldn't reach way point 6 due to search timeout (start links -1104014619 -1104014618 -832825699 -804886928 804886928 832825699 1104014618 1104014619 ), closest link to destination reached: 983304953 at 48.47348/34.99168, issues: illegal access
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in response. This was the  the issue at our end  and it is fixed now. Please check now from your end.

https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?apikey=key&app_id=id&app_code=code&representation=display&routeAttributes=summary&alternatives=0&mapMatchTolerance=50&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&departure=2022-03-30T21:00:00Z&arrival=2022-04-01T21:00:00Z&waypoint0=48.44465178998905,34.96006029852592;opening:2022-03-30T21:00:00Z;before:1&waypoint1=48.47320445868704,34.991180295542904;opening:2022-03-30T21:05:00Z;closing:2022-03-30T21:45:00Z;sort&waypoint2=48.46401993067931,34.97867142166844;opening:2022-03-30T21:00:00Z;closing:2022-03-30T21:30:00Z;before:3;sort&waypoint3=48.47320458546018,35.00203403643033;opening:2022-03-30T21:45:00Z;closing:2022-03-30T22:30:00Z;sort&waypoint4=48.441562775905375,34.95594137232717;opening:2022-03-30T21:00:00Z;closing:2022-03-31T23:00:00Z;before:5;sort&waypoint5=48.41997419510783,35.06206354332796;opening:2022-03-30T23:00:00Z;closing:2022-04-01T21:00:00Z;sort